# Find Duplicate Values in a column based on specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a table that holds actions against specific accounts, the actions are given a numbered SET of actions and within that SET they get a unique, sequential number. We ran into an issue where somehow one of the unique numbers had been duplicated and would like to check for more examples where this might have happened. The table looks a little like this:

```
Account | Action Set | Action No | Action Code
--------|------------|-----------|------------
  001   |     1      |     1     |    GEN
  001   |     1      |     2     |    PHO
  001   |     1      |     3     |    RAN
  001   |     1      |     3     |    GEN
  002   |     1      |     1     |    GEN
  002   |     1      |     2     |    PHO
  002   |     1      |     3     |    RAN
```

I have tried various things I've found through searches on here but can't find anything that looks like it fits my specific circumstances.

**For any given account number, I would like to find where within one Action SET the same Action Number is used more than once. I also need to return the full row, not just a count of how many there are.**

From the example above, I would expect to see these results, same account, same action set, same action number

```
Account | Action Set | Action No | Action Code
--------|------------|-----------|------------
  001   |     1      |     3     |    RAN
  001   |     1      |     3     |    GEN
```

I would post what I have tried so far but honestly the extent of the code I have written so far is:

```
SELECT
```

TIA

Mark

Comment: You should edit the question and provide examples of what you *do* want to find.  Your rows don't seem to match the criteria.

Comment: That's a pretty good start!

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I know you've already answered and your solution worked, but I have updated the original question with your suggestions in case it helps anyone else with the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.account = t.account and
                    t2.actionset = t.actionset and
                    t2.actionno <> t.actionno
             );
```

EDIT:

The above assumes that action numbers are different.  Otherwise you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*)
       from t t2
       where t2.account = t.account and
             t2.actionset = t.actionset 
      ) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the action numbers SHOULD be different, but trying to identify where they are the same. Your 2nd query didn't work for me, just returns all rows in the database. However, I did add an additional

Comment: sorry, pressed enter too soon, added an addition to the WHERE clause which fixed it for me, I've edited your response.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Select account,actionset,actioncode,actionno
from table
where (account,actionset)
IN
(
Select account,actionset from table
group by account,actionset
having count(distinct actionno)>1
)
group by account,actionset,actioncode,actionno
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't like the where clause being in brackets (account,actionset) -- getting an incorrect syntax error near ','

Comment: remove the brackets and then check @MarkJeffries

Comment: I did try removing the brackets, that did not resolve the issue. I get the error:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my solution for Getting duplicate records from table.

```
SELECT [ActionSet],ActionCode,[ActionNo]
FROM
(
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION by [ActionSet],[ActionNo] ORDER BY 
  [ActionNo]) as rnk FROM [dbo].[ActionAccount]
) t where t.rnk>1
```

Thanks .